# Confusion with androidx.compose.material3:material3

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose-material3

when I create a standard Jetpack Compose project in Android Studio and specify the version number of `androidx.compose.material3:material3` to something like `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0` the app does not recognize my devices dynamic colors anymore. Also do I have more options at `androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme.colorScheme` like ``

Can somebody explain this weird behavior?